# Паджинация и сортировка данных из MS SQL

Tags: java, java-ee

Пишу на NetBeans приложение по работе с данными из БД (MS SQL), столкнулся с задачей паджинации и сортировки. Собственно большинство примеров, что я нашел относятся к использованию каких то дополнительных компонентов, да и вообще работа идет с массивами, что мне не подходит. Собственно, привожу код над которым работаю (пример из книги Хорстмана):

```
package com.corejsf;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.inject.Named; 
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped; 
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class CustomerBean {
   @Resource(name="jdbc/mydb")
   private DataSource ds;

   public ResultSet getAll() throws SQLException {
      Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
      try {
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();        
         ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Customers");         
         CachedRowSet crs = new com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl();         
         crs.populate(result);
         return crs;
      } finally {
         conn.close();
      }
   }
}
```

И код html страницы:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
   <h:head>
      <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
      <title>#{msgs.pageTitle}</title>
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
      <h:form>
         <h:dataTable value="#{customerBean.all}" var="customer"
                      styleClass="customers" headerClass="customersHeader"
                      columnClasses="custid,name">
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.customerIdHeader}</f:facet>
               #{customer.Cust_ID}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.nameHeader}</f:facet>
               #{customer.Name}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.phoneHeader}</f:facet>
               #{customer.Phone_Number}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.addressHeader}</f:facet>
               #{customer.Street_Address}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.cityHeader}</f:facet>
               #{customer.City}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.stateHeader}</f:facet>
               #{customer.State}
            </h:column>
         </h:dataTable>
      </h:form>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

Cобственно вопрос - как в данном случае добавить паджинацию и сортировку?

Comment: И ту и другую задачи лучше решать на уровне базы. С сортировкой вообще просто, добавляете к запросу order by нужные-колонки. Для пагинации в зависимости от ситуации добавляются ограничения на количество выбранных записей (`top(N)` для MsSql) и дополнительные условия в запрос для отбора начиная с какого то места в `where` или с использованием `offset`

Comment: select * from customers ORDER BY id OFFSET 6 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY

Comment: По сортировке тут вроде не выйдет - имеется в виду чтобы можно было в полученной заполненной таблице сортировать, по щелчку кнопки, например, а не просто получать отсортированное.
А разве топ не выдаст просто N записей, все на одной странице?

Comment: Возвращение данных базой никак не зависит от ваших страниц. просите вернуть данных на одну страницу и по номеру страницы вычисляете offset. Хотя если сортировка на клиенте то надо смотреть что быстрее будет, тянуть из базы кусками или самому делать все на клиенте. И надо понимать, что чудес в БД не бывает и что бы выполнить offset он все равно где то внутри у себя пробегается по предыдущим записям хотя бы по индексу

Comment: Ну да, оно должно у клиента и обрабатываться - и сортировка, и все остальные функции.

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я так понял они ТС не подходят, ему надо на ходу сортировку на клиенте менять ... А в таком случае я бы и сам задумался стоит ли их повторно из базы тянуть ... А по джаве я сказать ничего не могу